# NameError in nested list comprehension with Python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

The objective is to convert the following for loop into nested comprehension list.

```
txt=['-100:200','-15:0','0:15','30:45']


all_t=[]
for t in txt:
    all_t.append([int ( idx ) for idx in t.split(":")])
```

into

```
all_t=[int(idx) for idx in t.split(":") for t in txt]
```

However, the compiler return an error

> NameError: name 't' is not defined

Appreciate for any help about this error

Comment: Write `for t in txt for idx in t.split(":")` instead. The order you should write the loops in is the same as if you were writing regular nested `for` loops.

Comment: @kaya3 upvoted but that would give `[-100, 200, -15, 0, 0, 15, 30, 45]` instead of `[[-100, 200], [-15, 0], [0, 15], [30, 45]]` on 2nd thought...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
txt=['-100:200','-15:0','0:15','30:45']
all_t=[[int(idx) for idx in t.split(":")] for t in txt]
print(all_t)
```